# Compiz problem in Ubuntu 13.10, ghostly stripes at the cube effect, How can i Fix it?

Tags: ati, compiz

I have installed Ubuntu 13.10 version on my pc but when I install and enable compiz desktop cube and try to turn it, there starts the problem, you see many ghostly stripes, unable to enjoy the cube effect.
something like that(this is not my picture)
http://www.udonet.com/laura/files/weird_desktop_effects.png
I tried many drivers, the free one and the privatives that appear in the list. How can I fix it?

This is my pc:

APU A8 5600K X4  3,6GHZ
Mother asrock A55M-DGS
DDR 3 8 gb Kingston
HDD 1 TB Toshiba
I will be grateful for your help!!! Excuse my English I'm from Uruguay

He instalado Ubuntu versión 13.10 en mi pc pero cuando instalo y activo el cubo de escritorio compiz, se inicia el problema, se ven muchas rayas espectrales, sin poder disfrutar del efecto cubo. algo así (no es mi foto) http://www.udonet.com/laura/files/weird_desktop_effects.png traté muchos DRIVERS, los libres y los privativos que aparecen en la lista. ¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Estaré muy agradecido con su ayuda!!! Los detalles de mi equipo están arriba!!!

Comment: Did you have a look at top or the system-monitor at that time? I only have effects like the ones visible in the screenshot if my system is under high load. Are you sure that you have installed the drivers correctly (e.g. is 3d acceleration working smooth on the system in general)?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the cube plugin is not supported in Unity enviroment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue it seems is to do with the Compiz GUI overlay that Saucy uses.  Specifically the animations and Fading Windows seem to be what's causing the issue.

Install the config manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open up the compizconfig-settings-managerGUI and Navigate to Effects and disable the "Animations" and "Fading Windows" check boxes.  Dont mess with any of the other settings in that tool unless you know what you are doing.

If you do decide to mess with it and break your GUI use this guide to reset compiz.
http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html